# cURL does not load on Apache Webserver

Tags: apache, curl, xampp, php-curl

I am running an XAMPP webserver with Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.

For a PHP script, I am using cURL to send some requests. However, when I run it, it says curl_init is undefined. I have extension=php_curl.dll uncommented in the php.ini file (and yes I do have it the dll in the ext directory)

I've tried copying libssh2.dll, libeay32.dll, and ssleay32.dll into different locations (i.e. Apache's bin directory, the ServerRoot directory, etc.), changing PHP versions, adding extension=curl into php.ini, among many other approaches I can't recall right now. I've been searching online for hours trying solutions to no avail. I can't install cURL on my computer as the server needs to be portable.